# Exclude WorkBook From Listing

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to make a macro work better in my sheet by excluding the specific name of the Work Book itself from the list of populated workbooks. I have tried entering an If like statement but I can't figure out the exact syntax/ where to add it that won't conflict with the rest of the macro.

Current Macro

```
Sub BrowseWorkbooks()
Const nPerColumn  As Long = 38          'number of items per column
Const nWidth As Long = 13                'width of each letter
Const nHeight As Long = 18              'height of each row
Const sID As String = "___SheetGoto"    'name of dialog sheet
Const kCaption As String = " Select Workbook"
                                        'dialog caption
Dim i As Long
Dim TopPos As Long
Dim iBooks As Long
Dim cCols As Long
Dim cLetters As Long
Dim cMaxLetters As Long
Dim cLeft As Long
Dim thisDlg As DialogSheet
Dim CurrentSheet As Worksheet
Dim cb As OptionButton
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    If ActiveWorkbook.ProtectStructure Then
        MsgBox "Workbook is protected.", vbCritical
        Exit Sub
    End If
    On Error Resume Next
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        ActiveWorkbook.DialogSheets(sID).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set CurrentSheet = ActiveSheet
    Set thisDlg = ActiveWorkbook.DialogSheets.Add
    With thisDlg
        .Name = sID
        .Visible = xlSheetHidden
        'sets variables for positioning on dialog
        iBooks = 0
        cCols = 0
        cMaxLetters = 0
        cLeft = 78
        TopPos = 40
        For i = 1 To Workbooks.Count
            If i Mod nPerColumn = 1 Then
                cCols = cCols + 1
                TopPos = 40
                cLeft = cLeft + (cMaxLetters * nWidth)
                cMaxLetters = 0
            End If
            Set CurrentWorkbook = Workbooks(i)
            cLetters = Len(CurrentWorkbook.Name)
            If cLetters > cMaxLetters Then
                cMaxLetters = cLetters
            End If
            iBooks = iBooks + 1
            .OptionButtons.Add cLeft, TopPos, cLetters * nWidth, 16.5
            .OptionButtons(iBooks).Text = _
                Workbooks(iBooks).Name
            TopPos = TopPos + 13
        Next i
        .Buttons.Left = cLeft + (cMaxLetters * nWidth) + 24
        CurrentWorkbook.Activate
        With .DialogFrame
            .Height = Application.Max(68, _
                Application.Min(iBooks, nPerColumn) * nHeight + 10)
            .Width = cLeft + (cMaxLetters * nWidth) + 24
            .Caption = kCaption
        End With
        .Buttons("Button 2").BringToFront
        .Buttons("Button 3").BringToFront
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        If .Show Then
            For Each cb In thisDlg.OptionButtons
                If cb.Value = xlOn Then
                    'Store the name of the Woorkbook to use it later
                    SelectedWorkBookName = cb.Caption
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next cb
        Else
            MsgBox "Nothing selected"
            Exit Sub
        End If
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Delete
    Set wbook = Workbooks(SelectedWorkBookName)
    wbook.Activate
    ActiveSheet.Unprotect
    Range("A1:P91").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Windows("Phoenix Remote Reconcile.xlsm").Activate
    Sheets("Paste Here").Select
    Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Sheets("Start-End").Select
    End With
End Sub
```

I was looking to add

```
If Workbook(i).Name Like "*Phoenix Remote Reconcile" Then        
       'Do Nothing 
Else
```

Updated:
...

```
For i = 1 To Workbooks.Count
            wbName = Workbooks(i).Name
            If Not wbName Like "*Phoenix Remote Reconcile*" Then

                iBooks = iBooks + 1

                If iBooks Mod nPerColumn = 1 And iBooks > 1 Then
                    cCols = cCols + 1
                    TopPos = 40
                    cLeft = cLeft + (cMaxLetters * nWidth)
                    cMaxLetters = 0
                End If

                cMaxLetters = Application.Max(Len(wbName), cMaxLetters)

                .OptionButtons.Add cLeft, TopPos, cLetters * nWidth, 16.5
                .OptionButtons(iBooks).Text = _
                Workbooks(iBooks).Name
                TopPos = TopPos + 13

            End If

            Set CurrentWorkbook = Workbooks(i)
            cLetters = Len(CurrentWorkbook.Name)
            If cLetters > cMaxLetters Then
                cMaxLetters = cLetters
            End If
            ....
```

Comment: Note that it will be `Workbooks(i)` - plural.

Answer (score 2):

```
Dim wbName as String
'......
For i = 1 To Workbooks.Count
   wbName = Workbooks(i).Name

   If Not wbName like "*Phoenix Remote Reconcile*" Then

        iBooks = iBooks + 1
        'don't use i below, since you're not adding every workbook...
        If iBooks Mod nPerColumn = 1 And iBooks > 1 Then '<<EDIT
            cCols = cCols + 1
            TopPos = 40
            cLeft = cLeft + (cMaxLetters * nWidth)
            cMaxLetters = 0
        End If

        cMaxLetters = Application.Max(Len(wbName), cMaxLetters)'<EDIT

        .OptionButtons.Add cLeft, TopPos, cLetters * nWidth, 16.5
        .OptionButtons(iBooks).Text = wbName '<<EDIT
        TopPos = TopPos + 13

   End If 'not skipping this workbook

Next i
'....
```

Comment: That doesn't work quite right. The Work Book"Phoenix Remote Reconcile" still populates in the list and other sheets do not. I have changed the work phrasing of "Phoenix Remote Reconcile" and that doesn't work. It is also expanding the window to be quite wide. Maybe explicitly exclude the Work Book "Phoenix Remote Reconcile"?

Comment: Couple edits above.   BTW your usage of "Workbook" and "Sheets" is confusing - a workbook *contains* worksheets: a workbook is a file and a sheet is a tab. If you use them interchangeably then it becomes difficult to follow your descriptions.

Comment: I am sorry about the workbook/sheet mix up. I corrected that above. I have inserted the code above with one problem. You removed the Set CurrentWorkbook = Workbooks(i); It Makes the macro fail. I kept it and now the workbook names do not appear properly. The workbook "Phoenix Remote Reconcile" is removed but "Local Remote Usage Sheet" is changed to "L". Any suggestions? I added my updated code above.

Comment: You don't use `CurrentWorkbook` for anything other than getting its name, so `wbName` is all you need. It looks like you only used a part of the code i posted, not the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean workbook or worksheets? Either way it is something like :

```
If InStr(Sheets(i).Name, "Phoenix Remote Reconcile") > 0 
''found it
else
''not there
endif
```

note you might want to surround both with UCASE() or LCASE() since VBA is case sensitive on matching.